# How to upload large files using chunk method using vue.js & laravel?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, laravel-5.3

Uploading file using html5 file reader & read the file and upload in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this url for the answer,

https://github.com/githubgobi/Fileupload-using-Chunk-Method